# Java integer input validation

Tags: java, validation

I am trying to validate input from a user.The user puts in Y coordinate a letter between (A-J) and x coordinate a number between (1-9).I can validate the y coordinate but am having trouble validating the x coordinate. I want it so if the user puts in something other than a number between 1 and 9 it keeps asking the user for valid input.

```
    do {
        // inner loop checks and validates user input
        do {

            System.out.println("Enter X Co-Ord (A-J), or Q to QUIT");
            letter = input.next().toUpperCase(); // upper case this for
                                                    // comparison
            if (letter.equals("Q"))
                break; // if user enters Q then quit

            String temp = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

            while (temp.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
                validString = false;
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
                letter = input.next().toUpperCase();
                col = temp.indexOf(letter);

            }

            if (temp.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
                validString = true;
                col = temp.indexOf(letter);

            }
            try {

                System.out.println("Enter Y Co-Ord (0-9)");
                row = input.nextInt();


            } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
                validInt = false;
                System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 -9");
            }

            catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            valuesOK = false; // only set valuesOK when the two others are
                                // true
            if (validString && validInt) {
                valuesOK = true;
            }
        } while (!valuesOK); // end inner Do loop
```

The output is:

Enter X Co-Ord (A-J), or Q to QUIT

d

Enter Y Co-Ord (0-9)

h

Please enter a number between 1 -9

Enter X Co-Ord (A-J), or Q to QUIT

Enter Y Co-Ord (0-9)

Comment: You'll want to align your text; one says 0-9, one says 1-9.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put a while loop around your `nextInt()` the same as you do when reading the letter:

```
  System.out.println("Enter Y Co-Ord (0-9)");
  row = -1
  while (row < 0) {
    try {
      row = input.nextInt();
      validInt = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 -9");
      row = -1;
      validInt = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Edited.  I dropped the validInt flag by mistake.

Comment: Please, use new syntax for try catch, it will look nicer.

Comment: What are you referring to by "validInt flag"? sorry, I'm new to programming.

Comment: I was meaning the validInt boolean value that you had inside the catch block in your original code above.

Comment: I'm afraid with the limited block of code here I don't see where an infinite look is coming from.  I would need to see further code outside this block to get the specific class of `input` for example.

Comment: I'll play around with it some more to see if I get it working.Thanks for all your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make the validation make more sense with the requirement, since human 's eye can skip easily the line `nextInt()`

```
String value = "";
System.out.println("Enter Y Co-Ord (1-9)");

while (!(value = input.next()).matches("[1-9]+")) {
    System.out.print("Wrong input. Insert again: ");
}

System.out.println(value);
```

Of course, when you get the right value, then you can parse it to integer again (safely !!!)